# regex: better way to match unknown number of letters in word

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm using regex to match a single word - with the letters in a certain specific order - but with an unknown length of the word.

I'm looking for a better way to do the following...

For example ...

```
if re.match('^(patient)(s{0,1})(m{0,1}e{0,1}r{0,1}g{0,1}e{0,1})$', Var):print True
```

var = 'patientmer' is true
var = 'patientsmer' is true
var = 'patientmrg'  is true
var = 'patientgmr'  is FALSE
var = 'patientsmrrge' is FALSE
var = 'patientsmerging' is FALSE

Some of the words get really long, so the

```
?{0,1}?{0,1}...
```

is cumbersome.

Comment: Replace `{0,1}` with `?`. Will it be less cumbersome? No idea, but that is a way to match *one or zero occurrences*. See [what it looks like](https://regex101.com/r/cC3vZ8/1).

Comment: To add to @WiktorStribiżew's comment, you could use list comprehension to insert a `?` before each letter.  For example, `if re.match('^(patent)(s?)({}?)$'.format("?".join("merge")), Var): print True`

Comment: @zondo: I assumed OP is using something like that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *limiting quantifier* `{0,1}` greedily matches *one or zero occurrences* of the pattern it quantifies.

The equivalent quantifier is `?`. See the [*Quantifier Cheat Sheet*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet):

> `A?`  Zero or one `A`, one if possible (greedy), giving up the character if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)

Thus, you can replace `{0,1}` with `?` to shorten the pattern.

See [what it looks like](https://regex101.com/r/cC3vZ8/1):

```
^(patient)(s?)(m?e?r?g?e?)$
```

And here is some [sample code](https://ideone.com/YcnROS) (thanks goes to [@zondo for his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602602/regex-better-way-to-match-unknown-number-of-letters-in-word/35602726#comment58889959_35602602)):

```
import re
term = 'patient'
pattern = '^({})(s?)({}?)$'.format(re.escape(term),"?".join("merge"))
print(pattern)
if re.match(pattern, 'patientmer'):
    print('found')
```

**Note** that `^` is not necessary if you plan to use the regex with the `re.match` method only.

Comment: Remove the `print(pattern)`, it is just a demo :) Actually, I think this is already quite concise.